# Using GPU outside of rendering in background mode

Tags: python, gpu, optimization

Is there any way to use your GPU outside of rendering? I'm using blender to generate and change objects with python in background mode. The resulting scene is never actually rendered, just exported to a new .obj file.

```
def create_plane(radius, location, rotation, name):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius = radius, location = location, rotation = rotation)
    new_mesh = bpy.context.active_object
    new_mesh.name = name
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')

for i in range(0, 1000):
    create_plane(1, (i, i, i), (i, i, i), "test_plane")
```

Executing this script either in background or in the blender GUI will result in no GPU usage whatsoever. 
[image: CPU - GPU usage]

[image: Settings]

Is there a way to utilize both my GPU and CPU for this use-case or have I been wasting my time the last couple of days trying to figure it out?

I'm pretty sure that CPU is actually better for the loop above, but I need to enhance performance so I'm just trying to investigate every possible solution. I'm obviously also doing way more than just generating a bunch of planes. I also know I can make use of copying one plane to improve performance in the code above. This code is purely there as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python you are writing is - even within Blender's interpreter - just Python: an interpreted language running on the CPU. There are ways to leverage the GPU in Python (eg. PyCUDA), but I would be very surprised that using the GPU would help here. As long as you are not part of Blender's own codebase (which entails recompiling the beast and diving into C++ or something that can be linked to it), you have to go through the Python API and whatever advantage there is to generating the planes on the GPU will be eclipsed by handing them over to Blender one by one though the interpreter.

Comment: Oh, I agree with you completely. Python is a bottleneck here, but I can't really get rid of it. The reason I'd like to try using the GPU as well is because once I'm completely done the scripts will probably take several hours to even a full day to run.


Even though python will make huge changes impossible it would save me  literally hours if I can just shave of milliseconds on certain parts.


According to everything I found so far it's impossible to use pyCUDA in blender. And it would really suck to not be able to use it since that would mean reinventing the wheel constantly.

Comment: The problem is: if you have to build every plane in Python, I don't really see what you could parallellise here. You'd only end up ferrying things back and forth to the GPU. If you have some large computation that ends up with your coordinates, then you can optimise that.

Comment: One potential micro optimisation is to copy the instances around with linked duplication. Then you don't have to create new meshes and get rid of some extraneous computation.

Comment: I just found an example of using pyCUDA in blender, it looks absolutely awful but I'll try using it for some parts. I do actually have some insane computations that end up with rotations or coordinates.

I tried using linked duplication before, but it somehow made it take longer. I'll give it another attempt, because in theory it should work. I will accept your answer because your pyCUDA reference made me take another look at it and actually find something. I'm pretty sure I'll end up having to dive into the blender codebase in the end which I really want to avoid :p

Comment: One last thing: maybe you could try to generate something more digest with whatever GPU-magic you wish and then import it into Blender. Maybe wavefront would fit your needs? Also, numpy is typically nicer to write than GPU stuff and is still a large bump in speed.